# Rewrite regex multiple params included slash in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm using NextJS v13 and I found the rewrite feature I tough if possible to create dynamic URL's like the following example:

`/folder/:cond(cond1\|cond2\|cond3)/:city([a-z\-?]+\-ci)/:bld([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-]+)`

I have the file **detail/index.js** inside **pages** folder for get that data.

In rewrite the condition is:

```
{
                source: '/folder/:cond(cond1\|cond2\|cond3)/:city([a-z\-?]+\-ci)/:bld([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-]+)',
                has : [
                    {type: "query", key: "cond", value: "(?<cond>.*)"},
                    {type: "query", key: "city", value: "(?<ci>.*)"},
                    {type: "query", key: "bld", value: "(?<property>.*)"}
                ],
                destination: '/detail/index'
            },
```

But I got 404 after test and I need to know why doesn't works?

Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to make sure point correctly in the folders needed for make a right rewrite.

If you use * in param you assume that all parametters are valid like the following example:

```
{
  source: '/buscador/:params*',
  destination: '/search'
}
```